# How to plot kmeans clustering on 4 dimensional data in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, k-means

I have the following at in numpy array.

```
[[5 1 1 2]
 [2 1 1 2]
 [5 2 1 1]
 [4 1 0 2]
 [6 1 0 1]
 [6 6 3 2]]
```

I used the following code to perform k-means clustering

```
    kmeans=KMeans(n_clusters=3)
    kmeans.fit(combs[j])
    centroids=kmeans.cluster_centers_
    labels=kmeans.labels_
    print("centroids",centroids)
    print ("labels",labels)
```

The output is

```
centroids [[ 5.    1.25  0.5   1.5 ]
           [ 6.    6.    3.    2.  ]
           [ 2.    1.    1.    2.  ]]
labels [0 2 0 0 0 1]
```

How can I plot the clusters using matplotlib or any other libraries ?

Comment: you can create a 3d plot and use color as the 4th dimension.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you actually have 5d data(considering labels of clustering but we will plot labels as the color od our data),
the most straightforward way to plot this is to delete the least important column of your data.
so with your given data, we have:

```
a = numpy.array([[5, 1, 1, 2], [2 ,1 ,1 ,2], [5 ,2, 1, 1], 
                [4 ,1 ,0 ,2], [6, 1, 0, 1], [6 ,6 ,3 ,2]])
```

and we consider your predicted labels for colors, so:

```
b =  labels=kmeans.labels_
#for example:
b = [0 , 1 , 2 ,2 ,1 ,2]
```

and now we plot our data using the first three columns of our data(in other words we don't use last column which is a[:,3]

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

img = ax.scatter(a[:,0], a[:,1], a[:,2], c=b, cmap=plt.hot())
fig.colorbar(img)
plt.show()
```

[image: 3d plot of a 4d data, note that we have 3 colors according to 3 clusters(white-orange-black)]

Answer (score 0):

I think it's weird to plot in 4D, as it doesn't make sense.
Or as most people as me can easily imagine the 4 dimension data.
You may need project to lower dimension plane ex:2D to visualize the results.